# Efficient/Proper way to add Images to MapControl - windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, bing-maps

I'm developing an App in which the map will be shown to user and I need to add around 10-12 images to the map at different GeoPoints each having 1KB of size.

I'm adding those images dynamically as per below:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Height = 35;
img.Width = 35;
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/myImage.png"));
img.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { Rotation = item.bearing };

MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(img, new Point(0.5, 0.5));
MapControl.SetLocation(img, new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = item.latitude, Longitude = item.longitude }));

myMap.Children.Add(img);
```

**My Problem is**

After I add those 12 images, my Map control becomes soo Laggy that while moving the map from one location to other, it hangs a lot.

So, is there any efficient way to add images to Map in windows phone 8.1 App.

**Edit:**

I've tried to add `MapIcons` to the Map, but in that case MapIcons were disappeared at specific zoom level, but i want to keep those MapIcons visible at any zoom level.

**So is there any way I can make `MapIcons` visible for every zoom level?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the MapIcon class instead, this would be handled better as the map is a native C++ control, so it has to do a lot of work to position XAML elements on the map. The MapIcon class is a native class so it renders much better. You will need to convert your image into a RandomAccessStream and then pass it into the MapIcon image property. This may help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/going_metro/2012/05/14/working-with-streams-creating-randomaccessstreamreference-from-image-downloaded-from-web/

You can then add the MapIcon's to the maps MapElements property.

Comment: So, when i add MapIcon to the MapControl, then MapIcons will be visible only on specific zoom level. When i zoom out, MapIcons were disappeared... In my scenario I want to keep those MapIcons visible at any zoom level on the map... Is this possible..  `Please help me`  and thanks for suggestion

Comment: In that case you are limited to using XAML elements which has the performance issue you are encountering. Note that performance of XAML elements has improved a lot in the UWP map control.